# Lower Bound of Polynomial Discriminant

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0$ with all $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$.  Assume that $f$ is square-free.  Let $D(f)$ be the polynomial discriminant of $f$.  Does there exist a lower bound on $|D(f)|$?

Mahler published an upper bound $$|D(f)| < n^n \left(\sum_i |a_i|\right)^{2n-2}$$

Any similar lower bound would be very helpful.

EDIT: For example, if all $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $|D(f)| \geq 1$.  If all $a_i$ are multiples of $s^{-t}$ where $s,t\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, then $|D(f)| \geq s^{-nt}$.  These are both very specific circumstances, so I was wondering if a general formula applied to all cases.

Answer (score 1):

The trivial lower bound $|D(f)|\ge0$ is the best you can hope for: whenever $f(x)$ has a double root, the discriminant will equal $0$.

Even if you restrict to the case where $f$ has no double roots, there is no lower bound in general. By continuity, slight perturbations of the coefficients of a polynomial with a double root will result in a polyonmial with arbitrarily small discriminant.

As you noted, if you restrict to polynomials with coefficients in $\frac1d\Bbb Z$, then the absolute value of the discriminant will be bounded below by $\frac1{d^n}$ when nonzero. I can't think of any other reason it would be bounded away from $0$.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I meant to state that $f$ is square-free.  I edited the initial post with this requirement.